# Writing a word across the slide

Tags: beamer, formatting, minipage

I wish to represent Sparsity across the screen as in the example given below:[image].

Here, is the frame so far:

```
\frame{   
\frametitle{What is a word?}

\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
   \hspace{20mm} ``cat''
\end{minipage}\hfill
    \pause
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
   \hspace{5mm} ``feline''
\end{minipage}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
   \hspace{22mm} 2
\end{minipage}\hfill
    \pause
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
   \hspace{5mm} 299,999
\end{minipage}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
\hspace{20mm}
     \begin{bmatrix}
       0 \\
       1 \\
       0 \\
       0 \\
       \vdots \\
       0 \\
       0 \\
     \end{bmatrix}
\end{minipage}\hfill
    \pause
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
  \hspace{6mm} \begin{bmatrix}
       0 \\
       0 \\
       0 \\
       0 \\

       \vdots \\
       1 \\
       0 \\
     \end{bmatrix}
\end{minipage}
}
```

Comment: A compilable example would be really nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making life difficult for yourself with all those minipages and `\hspace`s. Use one `minipage` per "column", and make use of `\uncover`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{What is a word?}

\begin{minipage}[c]{.3\linewidth}
\centering

\uncover<1->{``cat''}

\bigskip

\uncover<2->{2}

\uncover<3->{%
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
       0 \\
       1 \\
       0 \\
       0 \\
       \vdots \\
       0 \\
       0 \\
     \end{bmatrix}
\]
}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
\uncover<4->{\rotatebox{45}{\Huge\bfseries Sparsity!}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.3\linewidth}
\centering
\uncover<1->{ ``feline''}

\bigskip

\uncover<2->{299,999}


\uncover<3->{%
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
       0 \\
       0 \\
       0 \\
       0 \\
       \vdots \\
       1 \\
       0 \\
     \end{bmatrix}
\]}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Final slide looks like this:

[image]